# How do I merge structure changes from one Firebird's database to another? (not the data)

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

The problem is like this: my company has a service that cannot stop running for long periods of time and I was working on some modifications in the database structure used by this service.

Now that all my modifications are ready and well tested in a test bench environment, I want to export them to the running system. I could do this manually with IBExpert or FlameRobin, but I wanted to know if there is a more automated method for doing this (I feel dumb by spending a whole day creating tables, attributes, and so on one by one).

Is there?

Comment: There is similar question already, answers there might be useful, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1233980/723693

Comment: @ain OP is asking about automating that process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention IBExpert - It has the Database Comparer Tool which generates desired DDL to merge databases structure.

And as you know you can use IBEBlock to **fully automate** that process.

PS. Or **deploy your own app** using IBEScript.dll - which lets you use all functionalities of the IBEBlock scripting language

Please read: http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.IBEScriptDll

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the database compare feature of [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php) (Windows client).  It can compare whatever database objects you select and generate DDL to modify your destination database.  Unfortunately you will need the Pro edition, but there is a 30 day trial.